# How to call any objective c plugin method on click event of html button

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am new in phonegap development. I have one html page which contains one textfield and one button. I want to call my plugin method `-(void)nameOfMethod:( NSMutableArray*)paramArray withDict: (NSMutableDictionary*) options` which is inside the my plugin class and it getting text from my html text field and displaying alertview.I don't have have idea how to call this method via a javascript .I did a small part of coding in javascript

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="encryptdata.js"></script></head>
 <body>
 <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" value="" /> 
<input type="button" value="FetchR" onclick="fetchRelation()"/> </body>  
   encryptdata.js   
function fetchRelation() {     var getvalue=document.getElementById('confirmPassword').value;      //what is next step....... to send the data to the plugin class      }
```

but i don't have idea how to install that plugin in javascript and call its method in javascript . Is there anyone have idea about phonegap then plese help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to set the UIWebView delegate to a class and watch for the -webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: method. Just pass a URL to it by using window.location or  and parse the URL to call the Objective-C method you want.

Comment: Dear , would you please guide me by giving some example

Comment: The third and the fourth items might be interesting to you http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/